How to make a modified multiplication table?
I am being asked to make a multiplication table with the lower and upper limits set by the user. It's been requested that the top half of the table be starred out with * to avoid repeating numbers. I have the actual table code done, but I cannot figure out how to star out the top half of the table.
My code so far:
#Creating the lower and upper limit
lower_limit = int(input("Enter the minimum number for the multiplicatiom table: "))
upper_limit = int(input("Enter the maximum number for the multiplication table: "))
#creates the range using those limits given
table = range(lower_limit, upper_limit + 1)

for i in table:
    for j in table:
            print(("{:6d}".format(i * j,)), end='')
    print()

I think I need to do something by manipulating the columns, or maybe the rows? Like instead of printing the product of the two numbers, I need to print "*" but only for the top half of the table. Here is the example output:


You can do that by using if condition:
if j>i:
    print *
else:
    print ur number

How? for every value if not a square say 32 in the table it has two ways minimum 84 and 48, the 48 comes in bottom left part, while 84 comes in top right(as per logic of loop you used), the perfect squares like 25=5*5 comes in mid part making wall, to let top right part be marked by stars, you can verify that if multiplication belongs to top right or not using j>i which if true means top right, so you would be printing *, if not it is either the mid wall of square numbers(i=j) or bottome left for both you will print value
Therefore just change your for loop in your function:
for i in table:
    for j in table:
            if j>i:
                print(("{:<6s}".format('*',)), end='')
            else:
                print(("{:<6d}".format(i * j,)), end='')
    print()

Also you can improve this code by using {width} in place of 6, where width=len(str(j*j)) this would adjust spacing to support the max, and work when even multiplication exceed 6 digit

Didn't know reason for this being downvoted, yet reduced code and increased text, please check improvements in answer

The first snippet sure gives Python 2 vibes. :) It's okay though, since it's pseudo code. Also, the second could benefit from not indenting inconsistently. I didn't downvote that though.

Thanks I noticed that only now, changed it.

redoc's solution seems by far the most natural. However, for completeness, here's another possibility. Simply print the requisite number of stars at the end of the line.
lower_limit = int(input("Enter the minimum number for the multiplication table: "))
upper_limit = int(input("Enter the maximum number for the multiplication table: "))
for i in range(lower_limit, upper_limit + 1):
    for j in range(lower_limit, i + 1):
        print(("{:<8d}".format(i * j,)), end='')
    print( (upper_limit - i) * "*       " )

Output:
Enter the minimum number for the multiplication table: 3
Enter the maximum number for the multiplication table: 11
9       *       *       *       *       *       *       *       *       
12      16      *       *       *       *       *       *       *       
15      20      25      *       *       *       *       *       *       
18      24      30      36      *       *       *       *       *       
21      28      35      42      49      *       *       *       *       
24      32      40      48      56      64      *       *       *       
27      36      45      54      63      72      81      *       *       
30      40      50      60      70      80      90      100     *       
33      44      55      66      77      88      99      110     121     

